# How do I exit python program with control d?

Tags: python, user-input, exit

I have a python program that uses a while loop to check for a user input. I want it to keep running while a user enters an input, but quit when the user enters ctrl d. Currently, I get EOFError when typing ctrl d. I am new to python so any advice on how to fix this would be really helpful.

Here is a very simple example of my code:

```
while True:
  userInput = input()
  ...
exit()
```

Comment: On an uncaught `EOFError` the application should quit with a traceback already. Do you want to have something different than that?

Comment: @KlausD. I want it to quit quietly with no errors

Comment: Then you have to [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate loop gracefully when CTRL+C was pressed in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426451/how-to-terminate-loop-gracefully-when-ctrlc-was-pressed-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it with

```
try:
  while True:
      userInput = input()
      #any other work here
except EOFError as e:
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

The exit() keyword is also useful. It also improves readability.

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input()
    except EOFError:
        exit()
```